# How to handle quotation mark in data when using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am successfully reading almost all lines from my .tsv (tab separated) file.
However when the data itself contains quotation mark `CsvHelper` calls `BadDataFound` handler

**For example:**

> nm10296809\tWilliam "Billy" Cohen\t1\t1\tactor\tmore data

The character data itself is not enclosed to quotation in the data file.

When I configure my own `BadDataFound` hander, then the argument clearly shows that the problem is the 2nd field containing William "Billy" Cohen

**Question**

How to handle the quotation marks as data, within my 2nd field? As a workaround I can write a typconverter to filter out those lines by replacing the quotation mark with something special, then replacing back, but that smells a bit...

**What I tried so far:**

```
config.Quote = '\"'
```

Answer (score 1):

In previous CsvHelper versions there was an `IgnoreQuotes` config setting:

```
config.IgnoreQuotes=true;
```

In version 20.0 it was removed and replaced by the [Mode](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1659) property and `CsvMode.NoEscape` :

```
config.Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape;
```

Comment: I've tried both with Escape and NoEscape. For my data there is no difference, both eliminates the `BadDataFound` and imports the line, however both has the same issue: it replaces the double quote in the data to single quote, so in the C# string I got William 'Billy' Cohen instead of the original in the data file: William "Billy" Cohen.